# Setting var from jquery function inside jquery function doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i am trying to set a var using jquery inside another jquery function but it doesn't set the var. i have tryied several way. here is the last

```
jQuery(function($){

var pipeURL = "xxxxxxxxx.json";

var feedSuccess = function(data, status){
//var html = "<ul>";
var html = "";
var desc = "";
var description = "";
var start = "";
$.each(data.value.items, function(i,item){
//desc = item.description.replace("<br />"," ");
desc = item.description;
desc = desc.substring(0,600);
desc += "...";
descr = desc.replace(/(?:(?!UTC).)*/i,"");
$.getJSON(
      "https://graph.facebook.com/"+item.eid+"/?fields=start_time&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      function(data){

          start = data.start_time;
});

html += "<h3 class='pipes'><a class='pipes' href="+item.link+" target='_blank'>" + item.title +"</a></h3>"+"<p class='pipes'>"+start+"</p>"+
"<br/><a class='pipes' href="+item.link+" target='_blank'><img class='pipes' src='"+item['media:thumbnail'].url+"' ></a><br/>" ;
}); 
//html += "</ul>";
//Add the feed to the page
$("#insertFeed").empty().append(html);
};

$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: pipeURL,
success: feedSuccess,
timeout: 6000
});
});
```

the line which defines the var 'html' with the information inside fuction data "var start" doesn't run ok. it shows title ok and image ok but "start" shows a blank space.

Comment: If you would format your code correctly, you would probably be able to solve the issue yourself, or at the very least make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Move the `html` code UP, into the function where `start` is defined, right after it's defined

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var pipeURL = "xxxxxxxxx.json";

    var feedSuccess = function(data, status){
        //var html = "<ul>";
        var html = "";
        var desc = "";
        var description = "";
        var start = "";

        $.each(data.value.items, function(i,item){
            //desc = item.description.replace("<br />"," ");
            desc = item.description;
            desc = desc.substring(0,600);
            desc += "...";
            descr = desc.replace(/(?:(?!UTC).)*/i,"");
            $.getJSON(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/"+item.eid+"/?fields=start_time&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                function(data){
                    start = data.start_time;
                    html += "<h3 class='pipes'><a class='pipes' href="+item.link+" target='_blank'>" + item.title +"</a></h3>"+"<p class='pipes'>"+start+"</p>"+
                    "<br/><a class='pipes' href="+item.link+" target='_blank'><img class='pipes' src='"+item['media:thumbnail'].url+"' ></a><br/>" ;
                    //html += "</ul>";
                    //Add the feed to the page
                    $("#insertFeed").empty().append(html);                  
                });
            });
        });
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: pipeURL,
        success: feedSuccess,
        timeout: 6000
    });
});
```